# Exporting database from SSMS to Azure is sitting on "enabling indexes" without finishing

Tags: azure-sql-database

Having created an Azure SQL server resource, I'm now exporting a database from Management Studio 2014 to the Azure resource. It all seemed to be going well, but after going through all the tables, is now sitting on "enabling indexes" and has been for about 2 hours.

#### Deploy Database Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

The database is relatively small, only 1.5GB mdf, with a 180MB log. I have also tried exporting from SSMS to a local .bacpac file, and that also ends up sitting there for over an hour after going through the tables, but before showing the "enabling indexes" item.

It seems like SSMS is having trouble with the database for some reason, however this is a backup from production and has been in use without issues for a long time.

I'm not sure what to look for at this point. Are there some tools to check the database for errors which I can use here, to see why SSMS isn't able to finish exporting the db?

Comment: It may just be creating the indexes and throttled by the number of DTUs available, what wait types does the database currently have for waiting tasks?

Answer (score 1):

It is always important to use the latest SSMS for better experience with SQL Azure. Intellisense is now supported and many bugs related to SQL Azure have been fixed. Please download the latest version from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).

For importing a database to an empty SQL Azure database, please use the Data Migration Assistant. Download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595).